Deleting data from a file in C++
I'm not sure why if I store the name of the file in a variable "file_name" it doesn't remove or rename it. It won't let me run it, is there a reason for this?
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    string line;
    string f_user;
    string l_user;
    string book;


    cout<< "What is your first name?";
    cin >> f_user;
    cout<< "What is your last name?";
    cin >> l_user;
    string file_name= f_user + l_user + ".txt";

    cout << "What book would you like to return"<< endl;
    cin >> book;
    fstream writedata;
    fstream readdata;
    writedata.open(file_name);
    readdata.open("temp.txt");

    while (getline(writedata,line)){
        if (line != book){
            readdata << line << endl;
            cout << "Book Returned"<< endl;
            writedata.close();
            readdata.close();            
            remove(file_name);
            rename("temp.txt",file_name);
        }
    }
}


My bad! I forgot to put it in since it's part of a larger program

Nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless there's a good reason not to. In particular, writing std::endl into a file is a performance killer.

Side note: get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing fstream writedata; fstream readdata; writedata.open(file_name); readdata.open("temp.txt"); to fstream writedata(file_name); readdata("temp.txt");.

Also, a file that you're only writing to should be std::ofstream, and a file that you're only reading from should be std::ifstream.

The loop logic looks wrong; when the input matches book it closes the files, throwing away anything that hasn't yet been read.

And while I'm picking on you: shouldn't writedata be an output file, and readdata an input file? It's very confusing to read from a file named write... and write to a file named read....

Did you forget std::ios::out for your output file? See std::basic_fstream::open. You should be using ifstream and ofstream.

@DavidC.Rankin As the link you provided says, std::ios::out is the default for std::fstream, same as std::ios::in.

@Yksisarvinen - good catch, getting senile as I get old :)

This program should throw compile time errors because std::remove [cppreference] takes a const char* but you are passing an std::string. You should pass a pointer to the const char[N] the std::string holds instead. Same with std::rename. [cppreference]
For this to compile, this code should be:
std::remove(file_name.c_str());
std::rename("temp.txt", file_name.c_str());
The program’s runtime behaviour on the other hand depends on your environment setup, implementation defined requirements and various other nitty-gritty. Windows OS does not allow removal or renaming of files in use by any program whatsoever.
